# Customizing a sharepoint 2007 wiki site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wiki, customization, wikipedia

I have been asked to customize a SharePoint 2007 wiki site into a 'Wikipedia' like interface and functionality.

After a bit of goggling it turns out that wiki's are not that readily customizable!!

Any recommendations or resources?

**Edit:**

As, this site is part of the SharePoint portal it is not possible for me to port to a different tool. And, my solution requires to add content types and webparts on the wiki pages.

Now, I am following the [approach mentioned by Pavan to add a seperate wiki file for your customization](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pavankumar/archive/2009/02/25/custom-wiki-site-definition-with-custom-document-template-for-creating-wiki-pages.aspx).

If you have any other approach than this, please share.

Comment: What are the customizations you are looking for

Comment: I require to add content types and webparts on the wiki page. Like a template. But, as wiki pages do not support templates and I could not modify the wiki template. I am looking for a good work around.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout `Enhanced Wiki Edition` on `Community Kit for SharePoint` on Codeplex

http://cks.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Enhanced%20Wiki%20Edition&referringTitle=Home